# how to get the selected combobox value from QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have created a QTableWidget in which for a column I am setting a combobox QComboBox using setCellWidget function. It works fine .

This is how i set up the qtablewidget

```
cb = QComboBox()
cb.addItems(["Java", "C#", "Python"])
qtablewidget.setCellWidget(row_number, column_number , cb )
```

but now when I iterate through the QTableWidget , I cannot figure out how to get the selected value of the combobox for each row ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `cellWidget()` method to get the widget given the column and the row, and then use the `currentText()` method.

```
for r in range(qtablewidget.rowCount()):
    for c in range(qtablewidget.columnCount()):
        widget = qtablewidget.cellWidget(r, c)
        if isinstance(widget, QComboBox):
            current_value = widget.currentText()
            print(current_value)
```